# httpd-devel requires outdated version of glibc-common on CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos, rhel, software-installation, rpm

httpd-devel requires an outdated version of glibc-common on CentOS 6.3 x86_64 and Apache/2.2.15. It wants 2.12-1.80.el6 and I have 2.12-1.80.el6_3.3.x86_64 installed (via CentOS @update repo)

Here is the error when I run "yum install httpd-devel.x86_64"

> Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.i686 (base):

```
   Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.80.el6
   Installed: glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6_3.3.x86_64 (@updates)
       glibc-common = 2.12-1.80.el6_3.3
   Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.x86_64 (base)
       glibc-common = 2.12-1.80.el6
```

with "yum install httpd-devel.x86_64 --skip-broken", I get:

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:

```
> apr-1.3.9-3.el6_1.2.i686 from base apr-devel-1.3.9-3.el6_1.2.x86_64
> from base apr-util-devel-1.3.9-3.el6_0.1.x86_64 from base
> cyrus-sasl-devel-2.1.23-13.el6.x86_64 from base
> db4-cxx-4.7.25-17.el6.x86_64 from base db4-devel-4.7.25-17.el6.x86_64
> from base glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.i686 from base
> 1:httpd-devel-2.2.15-15.el6.vm.1.x86_64 from virtualmin
> libuuid-2.17.2-12.7.el6.i686 from base
> nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.9-11.el6.i686 from base
> openldap-devel-2.4.23-26.el6.x86_64 from base
```

Bottom line, **I can't get httpd-devel installed.**

Could this be a priority problem?

```
priority = 1 [asl-3.0]
priority = 1 [base]
priority = 1 [virtualmin]
priority = 1 [virtualmin-universal]
priority = 50 [epel]

repo id | repo name | status
C6.0-base |  CentOS-6.0 - Base | disabled
C6.0-centosplus | CentOS-6.0 - CentOSPlus | disabled
C6.0-contrib | CentOS-6.0 - Contrib |  disabled
C6.0-extras |  CentOS-6.0 - Extras |  disabled
C6.0-updates | CentOS-6.0 - Updates |  disabled
C6.1-base |  CentOS-6.1 - Base | disabled
C6.1-centosplus | CentOS-6.1 - CentOSPlus | disabled
C6.1-contrib | CentOS-6.1 - Contrib |  disabled
C6.1-extras |  CentOS-6.1 - Extras |  disabled
C6.1-updates | CentOS-6.1 - Updates |  disabled
C6.2-base |  CentOS-6.2 - Base | disabled
C6.2-centosplus | CentOS-6.2 - CentOSPlus | disabled
C6.2-contrib | CentOS-6.2 - Contrib |  disabled
C6.2-extras |  CentOS-6.2 - Extras |  disabled
C6.2-updates | CentOS-6.2 - Updates |  disabled
asl-3.0 | Atomicorp - - Atomic Secured Linux 3.0 | enabled: | 623
asl-3.0-testing | Atomicorp - - Atomic Secured Linux 3.0 (TESTING) | disabled
base | CentOS-6 - Base | enabled: | 6,346
c6-media |  CentOS-6 - Media | disabled
centosplus |  CentOS-6 - Plus | disabled
contrib | CentOS-6 - Contrib | disabled
debug | CentOS-6 - Debuginfo |  disabled
epel | Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 |  enabled: 7,627+125
epel-debuginfo | Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 - Debug |  disabled
epel-source |  Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 - Source | disabled
epel-testing | Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - Testing - x86_64 | disabled
epel-testing-debuginfo | Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - Testing - x86_64 - Debug | disabled
epel-testing-source |  Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - Testing - x86_64 - Source | disabled
extras | CentOS-6 - Extras | enabled: |  4
updates | CentOS-6 - Updates | enabled: | 0+523
virtualmin |  RHEL/CentOS/Scientific 6 - x86_64 - Virtualmin |  enabled: | 73
virtualmin-universal | Virtualmin Distribution Neutral Packages | enabled: | 187+1
```

Apache is from:

```
rpm -qi httpd
Name        : httpd                        Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 2.2.15                            Vendor: (none)
Release     : 15.el6.vm.1                   Build Date: Thu 17 May 2012 03:35:08 AM UTC
Install Date: Thu 28 Jun 2012 05:13:47 AM UTC      Build Host: srv1.cloud.virtualmin.com
Group       : System Environment/Daemons    Source RPM: httpd-2.2.15-15.el6.vm.1.src.rpm
Size        : 3067984                          License: ASL 2.0
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Thu 17 May 2012 03:09:42 PM UTC, Key ID e8dd3fa0a0bdbcf9
URL         : http://httpd.apache.org/
Summary     : Apache HTTP Server
```

Comment: question also asked on CentOS forums https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?viewmode=flat&topic_id=39202&forum=56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling priorities allowed "yum install httpd-devel" to work.

PS: i now have priorities as

```
priority = 10 [asl-3.0]
priority = 10 [asl-3.0-testing]
priority = 20 [virtualmin]
priority = 20 [virtualmin-universal]
priority = 30 [base]
priority = 30 [updates]
priority = 40 [extras]
priority = 50 [epel]
```

does this seem ok?

Answer (score 1):

Congrats:  you have encountered Dependeny Hell [tm].  Good news: It's always self-inflicted; no exceptions.

Virtualmin - I worked with Jamie on a project before outta SCONJ; this isn't like him - is providing an httpd-devel that violates the naming convention set forth by the fedora guidelines that in turn regulates enterprise linux packaging around CentOS as well.  THIS SHOULD NOT HAPPEN -- third-party repositories like Virtualmin should not overload the names of packages delivered upstream (like those in CentOS itself.

So, in short, you were using a bad repo.  Don't feel bad:  a lot of them have this issue, and there's no way to know otherwise.  Evan Dag used to do this in his RPMs.

I've never had to use the priorities setup, and I've been on RedHat/derivs since 98 or so.  I can't comment on whether your solution is valid, and the whole thing seems like a hack to get around a problem that the regs now avoid.

Disable the virtualmin repo.

```
sed -i '/^enabled/r\enabled=0' /etc/yum.repos.d/name-of-virtualmin.repo-file
```

Only enable it on the command line for one-off things, and understand until they get it fixed that it will cause dependency issues.

```
yum --enablerepo virtualmin [command]
```

Jamie is a VERY smart and capable dev, and his product and repos should be better.  This can only be a short-term thing.